# Connecting to second COM port closes first COM port connection

Tags: java, swing, serial-port

I want to be able to connect to multiple, identical devices, so that my program acts as a controller over all these devices.
I've written a program that allows me to connect to a device via RS232. I run it using java 
1.7 with Java Comms on a Windows Vista laptop. I use a USB to RS232 adapter from Startech (type ICUSB2324X) which allows me to have 4 aditional COM ports/RS232 connections. The program works perfectly when I connect only 1 device at a time.
As soon as I connect to an additional device on a different COM port, the second device connects like it should but the first connection seems to be lost. I don't get any errors.

I have a swing GUI that allows me to add new instance of a jPanel (called ControllerPanel) to it, each panel contains a jCombobox that lists the available COM ports and allows you to choose a port to connect to. I can add as much ControllerPanels to my frame as I want, no problems there. The selected port is stored as "preferredPort". Hitting "connectButton" triggers this piece of code within my ControllerPanel class (and after that the problem starts):

```
private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (!connectedToPort){
        String preferredPort = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        connectToPort(preferredPort);

    }else{
        try {
            closeConnection();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                         Logger.getLogger(ControllerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This triggers my connectToPort method

```
private void connectToPort(String preferredPort) { 
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
    portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

        if (portId.getName().equals(preferredPort)) {
            try {
                serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("deviceController", 2000);
            } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                System.err.println(e);

            }
            try {
                outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();

                printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.err.println(e); 
            }
            try {
                serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEventListener) this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
                serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);


            try {
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(38400,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
          }
       }
    }
    connectedToPort = true;
}
```

Connecting the first time to a port works perfectly fine. When I try to connect to a new port from new instance of ControllerPannel seems to kill the connection of the first. Every time I try to connect an additional device on a different COM port terminates the existing connection.
I don't understand how the second connection interferes with the first one, as both connections originate from a different instance of ControllerPanel. I could use some help, as I don't know where to start. I am currently not doing any multithreading (as I am not sure if this may solve my problem), should I? All suggestions are welcome. If you need more code in order to be able to help, I'll gladly provide it.

Comment: If you run two instances of the program with different devices/ports, does the problem go away? It could be finicky hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried running two instances and the problem goes away. So I don't think the problem is hardware related. Any other ideas?

Comment: No unfortunately, I'm sadly not acquainted with this hardware and software library. The comments should be able to bump the question and get it more noticed, however. Best of luck, and sorry again.

Comment: There's nothing to apologize about, thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the variables that represent the serial connection were set to static. I replaced the keyword static with private and this fixed the problem.